# Dual boot Ubuntu / Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, grub, dual-boot

Имею две установленные системы на разныхъ nvme девайсах.
Подскажите как настроить grub, что-бы можно было выбрать Windows 11 при запуске системы.
Устанавливал системы я отдельно друг от друга.

Результат `fdisk -l`:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 1000214527 999163904 476.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme1n1p1  2048     34815     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme1n1p2 34816 500117503 500082688 238.5G Microsoft basic data
```

Comment: Вот здесь есть всё, что надо — https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dual_boot_with_Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Отредактируйте меню загрузки с помощью средства «Конфигурация системы».

1. Нажмите <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, В строке «Выполнить» наберите `msconfig`, нажмите <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Откроется окно конфигурации системы. Перейдите на вкладку «Загрузка».
2. В верхней части открывшейся вкладки находится поле со списком операционных систем. Справа каждой записи добавлен комментарий об операционной системе, в которую выполнен вход, и системе, загружаемой по умолчанию. Для изменения системы, загружаемой по умолчанию, выберите в поле списка запись о нужной операционной системе и нажмите кнопку «Загружать по умолчанию». В результате выполненной операции справа от названия появится соответствующий комментарий.
   Для удаления ненужной записи выберите ее из списка и нажмите кнопку «Удалить».
3. После выполнения всех действий нажмите кнопку «Применить» и закройте окно конфигурации системы. Вам будет предложено перезагрузить компьютер. Изменения вы увидите во время следующей загрузки компьютера.
   Либо выбирать через <kbd>F8</kbd> возможно получится

Comment: К сожалению этот сопособ мне неподходит. Windows не видил Linux установленный на другом физическом носителе.